# Angular2 - Reload a component after re-clicking the link

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, reload, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to reload an Angular2 children component after re-clicking a link.

```
//Component 
public clickedLink(event) {
    // should reload the page before doing stuff
    //.. doing something .. 
}
```

I tried ChangeDetectorRef and Application.tick(), but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: what about `window.reload()` ?

Comment: It will bring back to the parent's component. I am in the child component

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should not normally need to reload a component after re-clicking a link?

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate to your route path whichever you want to redirect to

```
 constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute,
      private r : Router) {}

    reloadWithNewId(id:number) {
        this.r.navigateByUrl('my/' + id + '/view');
    }
```

Comment: I am refreshing the page using emit. So the url stay the same for different component.

Comment: in that case just navigate to that url

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should not be reloading the page.** Just get back the data.

Suppose you are on the user detail page and on click of something you need to reload the page.

Say

```
class UserComponent{
constructor(){}
ngOnInit(){this.getUser()}
getUser(){...}
click(){...
      this.getUser()
   }
}
```

Here on click, you should get the user back, so the component will have the latest data and it will automatically render the values.

It will give user very good experience.

Tell me if your use case is different.